# How to access husband's iCloud account?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I have been using my husband's Apple ID for my iCloud account. Now I have noticed that my iCloud backup is off and I need to turn it on.

I need to access my account since my husband already changed the password for his Apple ID and he wont tell the new password.

What can I do? Every time I try to turn on iCloud backup it asks for the password to my husband's account? I need to update and download some apps.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent, Please improve your question with grammar and stuff.

Comment: It is impossible to "delete" an Apple ID. If you need to change the ID used by the iPhone you can do so somewhere in Settings, probably Settings>iCloud

Answer (score 5):

1. Plug your phone into iTunes to get a backup
2. Get your husband to either remove your phone from his iCloud find my phone by logging into iCloud.com ( or he can type the password to allow you to remove his iCloud from your phone or he can tell you the password and the. Change it a third time)

Until you have find my phone turned off with his permission, your iPhone won't let you use it with another Apple ID - this is activation lock and designed to make stolen phones less valuable to theft.